# Platformer Script error CS1525: Unexpected symbol platformSpeed', expecting(', )',,', ;',[', {', or'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code is returning the following error:

Assets/Scritps/Moving_Platform.cs(13,101): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `platformSpeed', expecting`(', `)',`,', `;',`[', `{', or`'

In monodevelop, it seems that Unity is reading the * after new Vector3.right as a part of that, because both that expression and the following * are highlighted in the same blue tint.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Moving_Platform : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform platform;
public Transform startTransform;
public Transform endTransform;
public float platformSpeed = 2; 

void FixedUpdate()
{
    platform.rigidbody.MovePosition(platform.position * new Vector3.right * platformSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.green;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube (startTransform.position, platform.localScale);
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube (endTransform.position, platform.localScale);
}
```

}

I am using the most recent version of Unity, version 4.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `new` before `Vector.right`.

```
platform.rigidbody.MovePosition(platform.position * Vector3.right * platformSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

EDIT:
You propably want move the object from `platform.position` by `Vector3.right * platformSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime`. So you want use `add (+)` move to the original position.

```
platform.rigidbody.MovePosition(platform.position + (Vector3.right * platformSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
```

Comment: When I do that, I get 3 new errors:Moving_Platform.cs(13,58): error CS0019: Operator `*' cannot be applied to operands of type `UnityEngine.Vector3' and `UnityEngine.Vector3',         Moving_Platform.cs(13,36): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Rigidbody.MovePosition(UnityEngine.Vector3)' has some invalid arguments,Moving_Platform.cs(13,36): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `UnityEngine.Vector3' The reason I put the "new" there was because that seemed to fix these errors, but then gave me the other error, the one first posted